# Common boundary point of convex bodies

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity

Let $K_1, \ldots, K_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be some convex bodies (i.e., compact with nonempty interior) such that for each subset $I \subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$ the set

$$\left( \bigcap_{i \in I} K_i \right) \setminus \left( \bigcup_{i \not\in I} K_i \right)$$

has nonempty interior. Does it follow that the intersection of the boundaries $\bigcap_{i \in I} \partial K_i$ is nonempty?

It seems to be true for $n \leq 3$ although I don't have a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is whether the intersection of the boundaries of *all* the sets $K_i$ is nonempty, the answer is no for $n=3$.

Let $K_1$ be the unit ball with center $(0,0,0)$, $K_2$ the unit ball with center $(0,0,1)$, and $K_3$ a thin cylinder of radius $0.1$ around the $z$-axis, with bases at heights $-2$ and $2$. The condition on intersections is clearly satisfied.

The boundaries of $K_1$ and $K_2$ intersect in a circle $C$ of radius $\sqrt{3}/2 > 0.5$, so $K_3$ is disjoint with $C$.